# How Do I Fix This Error "pygame.error: unable to open file 'PaddleHitSound.mp3'"?

Tags: python, audio

I am making a bunch of arcade games for my dad on PyGame, and this one is Pong. That's beside the point, I am trying to make it play audio [the .mp3 is in the same folder] with my code

Instead of working, I get this error: 
pygame.error: Unable to open file 'PaddleHitSound.mp3'

I have tried converting it to a .wav file and setting the file it looks for to: PaddleHitSound.wav. I tried giving it the full destination of the file, even though it was already in the same folder.

```
pygame.mixer.Sound("PaddleHitSound.mp3")
pygame.mixer.Sound.play(0)
```

I have this code in a collision area and want it to play the audio on the collision. It, unfortunately, can't find/open the file.

The error is [again]: pygame.error: Unable to open file 'PaddleHitSound.mp3'

Comment: Can you include your directory structure and where the sound file is in relation to the code?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by directory structure? I can only imagine that by 'where the sound file is in relation to the code' you mean where it's at in the code. Sorry, I'm 13, and just moved from C++ to Python, sooo... yeah. Thanks for the reply! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. First，according to documents https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound, `The Sound can be loaded from an OGG audio file or from an uncompressed WAV`.
2. Since you have try the wav file, make sure you have done the `pygame.init()`;
3. Add `pygame.mixer.init()`, if you get this error `pygame.error: DirectSoundCreate: No audio device found`, you don't have audio device on you computer or your audio device got some erro. You should plug in a headphone and try again.
   Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, man! I think I actually spelled it wrong when it was a .wav file, as I did it again, and it works now! Thing is, it is SO LOUD, how do I set the volume? Thanks! :)

Comment: @Inferno-Interactive There is a `pygame.mixer.Sound.set_volume` function in above documents, you may check that.